# tf2 buffer lookupTransform fails, tf_echo and rostopic echo /tf_static work fine

Tags: ros, transform, ros-kinetic, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having difficulties getting a transformation from a robot to the static world frame in a custom node I am writing. I am using Kinetic and I have a robot with a kinect sensor on board providing PointCloud2 data. I am using the `robot_state_publisher` node to take care of the tf transforms.

Here is a snippet of my launch file that calls the `static_transform_publisher` and `robot_state_publisher`:

```
<!-- send static transform -->
<node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="vehicle_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 $(arg world_frame) $(arg namespace)$(arg base_link_frame)" />

<!-- start robot state publisher -->
<node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen" >
  <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
  <param name="tf_prefix" type="string" value="$(arg namespace)" />
</node>
```

**NOTE: the $(arg) values are passed in via command line to the launch file. They should be "world", "robot", "/base_link", and "robot", respectively**

The reasoning for calling the `static_transform_publisher` was that I was not getting a `base_link -> world` transformation. In other words, I couldn't seem to get `robot_state_publisher` to output a transformation from the robot's frame to an inertial world frame. (I'd be happy to hear suggestions on this, although this is not the main intent of this question).

The node I have is running the following code:

```
tf2_ros::Buffer tfBuffer;
tf2_ros::TransformListener tfListener(tfBuffer);
geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transformStamped;

try {
    transformStamped = tfBuffer.lookupTransform("world", "robot/kinect_depth_optical_frame", ros::Time(0));
    std::cout << transformStamped << std::endl;
}
catch (tf2::TransformException &ex) {
    ROS_WARN("%s", ex.what());
}
```

All I am trying to do at this point is find the transformation between the kinect's optical frame and an inertial "world" frame. When I run this node from a launch file, I get the following exception:

```
[ WARN] [1522870890.897427898, 4.330000000]: "world" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.
```

This error persists when I use anything as the first argument, with "world" being replaced with whatever is passed in. When I run `rosrun tf2_tools view_frames.py`, I get a TF tree that looks exactly how I'd expect a working system to look. Unfortunately, since this is my first post, I don't have enough points to upload an image to this question. (Hopefully I can edit it soon to upload the image...)

When I run `rosrun tf tf_echo robot/kinect_depth_optical_frame world` in a terminal, I get the following output:

```
At time 0.000
- Translation: [-0.020, -0.060, -0.050]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.500, -0.500, 0.500, 0.500]
            in RPY (radian) [1.571, -1.571, 0.000]
            in RPY (degree) [90.000, -90.000, 0.000]
```

Regardless of whether or not the transformation is actually correct, the fact that I am getting a response means that this transformation is set up and I should be able to look it up using `lookupTransform` in my node. I also get an output from `rostopic echo /tf_static` that looks correct as well (I can add that if requested).

I apologize for the long winded explanation, but I am at a loss here. Why would `tf2_echo` function properly, but `lookupTransform` not be able to find the frames that are clearly there when viewed by other means? As an additional note, when debugging the node, the `tfBuffer` object has nothing--i.e. `tfBuffer.allFramesAsString()` returns nothing and `tfBuffer._frameExists("world")` returns false.

Does anybody have any ideas on what my issue could be? Am I initializing the buffer incorrectly, or calling `lookupTransform` incorrectly? Any advice is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287540/tf2-buffer-lookuptransform-fails,-tf_echo-and-rostopic-echo-/tf_static-work-fine/) by [patnolan33](https://answers.ros.org/users/34499/patnolan33/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-04-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-04**:
Buffers need time to be filled by their listeners. How much time are you giving your `tf2_ros::TransformListener` to fill the buffer you pass? If you don't give it any time, things won't work. All the other tools 'work', because they wait for transforms to become available.

**Comment by [patnolan33](https://answers.ros.org/users/34499/patnolan33/) on 2018-04-04**:
That makes sense, but I'm not exactly sure how to answer your question. I have a `ros::Rate loop_rate(10)` defined in my node's main, but the above transform lookup is done in the callback for the kinect's point cloud topic. Is there a way to set that wait time for the `tf2_ross::TransformListener`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using a class to wrap all this, just make the buffer and listener members and initialise them in your ctor. If not, put them in a scope other than this callback and do the same.

If that's impossible, use the `timeout` argument to `lookupTransform(..)` and set it to a non-zero value. That will make `lookupTransform(..)` wait for a maximum of `timeout` seconds before attempting the actual transformation.

See [tf2_ros::Buffer::lookupTransform(..)](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/tf2_ros/html/c++/classtf2__ros_1_1Buffer.html#acabbd72cae8f49fb3b6ede3be7e34c55).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [patnolan33](https://answers.ros.org/users/34499/patnolan33/) on 2018-04-05**:
Alright great, that worked. Don't know how I missed that timeout argument to `lookupTransform`. I'd like to wrap it in a class as per your first comment, but the buffer was the issue. Thank you for your help! (Do I have to post an answer, or can I somehow mark your comment as the answer?)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-05**:
Check also `canTransform(..)` in the same class.